# Lighthouse thinks typewriter animation is layout shift

Tags: reactjs, lighthouse

As the title suggests, I'm using [`typewriter-effect`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/typewriter-effect) package and that gives me a cool typewriter animation.

Yet, Lighthouse thinks it is a sort of layout shift and that counts towards the CLS score. Are there any ways to migrate that besides either ignoring the score or stop using the animation?

[My site](https://mwskwong.com) BTW.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this is the proper behavior of the Lighthouse with shifting layouts.

To solve the issue you need to consider the section size, so use the `width` and `height` in the **container** of the typewriter section, so the lighthouse knows the size of that element before rendering the whole typewriter section and animations.

For example:

```
function TypeWriterSection () {
  return (
   <div className={{height: '350px', width: '500px'}}>
     // ...
   </div>
  )
}
```